# A summary of different cases of interaction effects, how do you interpret?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, interaction

I know there are lots of questions/answers about dealing with interaction effects in regressions on this site, but I think there is a need to summarize a bit. I don't know if there is a standard way to deal with it, or if it makes sense. I just want to make a list of occasions when people may see interaction effects, and discuss about how to deal with them in each condition.

If we are doing regressions with one covariate/independent variable/predictor or whatever you may call it, things are always easy. You just need to built a model like

```
               Y ~ B0 + X + error
```

and there is no need to bother interactions. If we have multiple covariates, say 2, things become complex. What I usually do is to build a model without interaction effects first:

```
               Y ~ B0 + X1 + X2 + error
```

Let's call it RWRTI (regression without interaction terms). Then I decide what to do next based on the results. Perhaps I build another model with interaction terms:

```
               Y ~ B0 + X1 + X2 + X1*X2 + error
```

Let's call it RWI (regression with interaction terms).

If I firstly run RWRTI, I will list some cases with questions:

***(1) Both X1 and X2 are not shown to be significant in RWRTI.***

For me, I simply report the non-significance of both covariates, and finish. I don't do RWI. I don't think anything would change with RWI. Do you think it might change?

***(2) Both X1 and X2 are shown to be siginificant in RWRTI.***

For me, a natural reaction is to use RWI to check interaction terms. But this is sometimes problematic for me, e.g. After seeing the result from RWI, I might have 5 conditions :

```
 1. X1 is significant, X2 is not, X1*X2 is significant.

    This perhaps indicates that the significance of X2 is due to the interaction. 
    So I report X1 as significant, and for X2 I report the interaction effect.

 2. Both X1 and X2 are significant, X1*X2 is not significant.

    This is simple, since I just need to report the main effects of both.

 3. All X1, X2 and X1*X2 are significant.

    I need to report 2 main effects and an interaction

 4. Both X1 and X2 are not significant, but the interaction term X1*X2 is significant

     In this case, it means both significance of X1 and X2 are due to the interaction. 
     So I only report the interaction.

 5. Nothing is significant.

    I have never seen this happen.
```

***(3) X1 is shown to be significant, but X2 is not with RWRTI.***

For this case, I am a bit confusing. Since only one covariate is significant, should I still try RWI to see the interaction? Is it possible that the significance of X1 is due to its interaction with the other non-significant covariate X2? Before I thought I might be able to remove X2 from the model, since it is non-significant, but someone suggests not to remove it, because we cannot build models solely based on significance. Anyway, if I do not remove X2 and do a RWI, I will again facing the following conditions:

```
 1. X1 is significant, X2 is not, X1*X2 is significant.

    This perhaps indicates that the significance of X1 is partialy due to the interaction. 
    So I report X1 as significant, and I also report the interaction effect between the 2.

 2. Only the interaction term X1*X2 is significant

     In this case, it means the significance of X1 is from the interaction. 
     So I report the interaction effect only.

 3. Nothing is significant.

     This is something weried, but I really have this problem recently (for a mixed linear model). 
     The RWI model cancels out everything, no main effects, no interactions. 
     I have difficulty interpreting the results, because nothing is significant.

 4. Both X1 and X2 are significant, X1*X2 is not significant.

    I have never seen this happen.

 5. All X1, X2 and X1*X2 are significant.

    I have never seen this happen.
```

OK, I've listed all possible cases one might see when dealing with multiple regression.  How do you deal with each case? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know why this question got a downvote without a reason. Please leave a reason before a simple click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole approach here seems wrong, although I can certainly see where you got it. Also, the things you have never seen happen *do* happen, and not infrequently.

Here is a better plan:

1. *Think* about your model. Should there be an interaction? What does the literature say? What does your intuition say? What about your hypotheses, research questions etc.?
2. Make graphs. Graph IVs vs. DV, IVs vs. IV, IVs vs. DV at different levels of the other IVs etc. Include a smoother in any scatterplots you make.
3. Think some more.
4. If more than one model seems reasonable (after step 1-3 but before running models) run them all.
5. Carefully compare the models. Do *not* base this comparison solely (or even mainly) on significance; also consider the following:
   a. Does adding a term affect the other parameters (*not* their significance, but their effect size)?
   b. Does adding a term make the model more coherent?
   c. Does a nonsignificant and small effect contradict the literature?
   d. If an interaction is included, you nearly always want to include all the main effects that make up that interaction.
6. Consider including more than one model in your report/paper/whatever. Remember "all models are wrong, but some models are useful" (George Box). In many fields, there is no one *best* model; including more than one model allows your readers to think.
7. Certainly do *not* base your decision about whether to include an interaction on whether the main effects in a model without the interaction are significant. The whole point of an interaction is that, if one is present, the main effects should not be looked at alone.

Comment: (+1) This mostly seems like solid advice. However, wouldn't (2) be prone to finding some spurious association? For example, you shouldn't look at some graphs and _then_ decide to test one-sided in a $t$-test. Does the same not apply to choosing whether to include an interaction term?

Comment: That's a good point. I think it gets a bit tricky. One thing would be to use some form of cross validation.  There are reasonable people who differ on just how much of the model has to be propounded a priori. It might happen that an interaction you hadn't thought of a priori nevertheless has strong substantive justification.